# new item added to top of recyclerView moves previous items like in google keep?

Tags: android

I want to make a notepad app.I want that the new note that is added appears on the top(done by reversing the arraylist) and I want to move previous item in the recyclerView as in the link given below but i am not able to do that. I have tried many a times but all the items are loaded at once in the recyclerView.I am using SQLite DB to fetch the items in recyclerView.Please help

**main activity:**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int count=0;
private ArrayList<DataBean> getlist=new ArrayList<>();
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Context context;
public static final String TAG=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private VivzAdapter mAdapter;
private TextView create;
private ImageView mAdd;
private StaggeredGridLayoutManager mStaggeredGridLayoutManager;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

   mAdd= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add);
   create= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create);
    mAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });




    mRecyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.drawableList);
/*    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new ScaleInLeftAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().setMoveDuration(1000);
    mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().setAddDuration(1000);
    mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().setMoveDuration(1000);
    mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().setRemoveDuration(1000);
    mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().setMoveDuration(1000);
    mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(1000);*/
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mStaggeredGridLayoutManager=new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,1);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mStaggeredGridLayoutManager);

    mAdapter=new VivzAdapter(Main2Activity.this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        getlist = getAllData();

        mAdapter.setNotesArrayList(getlist);



}


public ArrayList<DataBean> getAllData(){
    ArrayList<DataBean> list = new ArrayList<>();
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("NoteDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mynote" +
            "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,title VARCHAR NOT NULL," +
            "note VARCHAR NOT NULL,day INT,month INT,year INT,hour INT," +
            "minute INT,fontColor INT,backColor INT);");

    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM mynote", null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id=cursor.getInt(0);
        String title = cursor.getString(1);
        String note=cursor.getString(2);
        Log.d(TAG,"note:"+note);
        int day=cursor.getInt(3);
        int month=cursor.getInt(4);
        int year=cursor.getInt(5);
        int hour=cursor.getInt(6);
        int minute = cursor.getInt(7);
        int backColor=cursor.getInt(8);
        int fontColor=cursor.getInt(9);
        DataBean data = new DataBean();
        data.setId(id);
        data.setTitle(title);
        data.setNote(note);
        data.setDay(day);
        data.setMonth(month);
        data.setYear(year);
        data.setHour(hour);
        data.setMinute(minute);
        data.setBackColor(backColor);
        data.setFontColor(fontColor);
        count++;
   //   Log.d(TAG,"count"+count);
        list.add(data);
    }
    return list;
}
[
```

**the adapter Code:**

```
public class VivzAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VivzAdapter.ViewHolderCar> {
private ArrayList<DataBean> mNotesArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private int lastPosition=-1;
private String title;
private String note;
private int month;
private int day;
private int year;
private byte[] img;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
Context context;

public VivzAdapter(Context context){

    mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

    this.context=context;

}

public void delete(int position,View view){
    if(mNotesArrayList!=null && mNotesArrayList.size()!=0) {

       DataBean current = mNotesArrayList.get(position);
        String titl = current.getTitle();
        db = view.getContext().openOrCreateDatabase("NoteDB", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM mynote WHERE title='" + titl + "'");
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM image WHERE title='" + titl + "'");
        mNotesArrayList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}




public void setNotesArrayList(ArrayList<DataBean> mNotesArrayList){

    this.mNotesArrayList=mNotesArrayList;
   notifyItemInserted(0);
   lastPosition=0;
    Collections.reverse(mNotesArrayList);


}

@Override
public ViewHolderCar onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   View view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

    ViewHolderCar viewHolder=new ViewHolderCar(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderCar holder,int position) {

    DataBean currentData=mNotesArrayList.get(position);



     day = currentData.getDay();
     month = currentData.getMonth();
     year = currentData.getYear();
     holder.mNote.setText(currentData.getNote());
     String note1 = currentData.getNote();

     if (note1.trim().length() <= 7) {
         holder.mNote.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 54);
     } else if (note1.trim().length() <= 20) {
         holder.mNote.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 40);
     }

     holder.mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(currentData.backColor);
     holder.mNote.setTextColor(currentData.fontColor);




       //     setAnimation(holder.mRelativeLayout, position);


}

private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {

    if(position==lastPosition) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.push_left_in);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mNotesArrayList.size();
}

 class ViewHolderCar extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{



    private TextView mNote;

     private ImageView mDel;
     private ImageView mEdit;
     private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    public ViewHolderCar(View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        mNote= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.noteValue);

        mDel= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        mEdit= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
        mRelativeLayout= (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layBackColor);

        mDel.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        delete(getAdapterPosition(),view);

    }
}
```

}

The following link contains a video of what i want to do:

[this video](http://artoogithubdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/bounty/keep2.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reversing the ArrayList, when creating it add things onto it in reverse, I'm not sure how you're doing it but normally it consists of a for loop, instead of starting at 0 start at array.size and count backwards to 0.

Then you need to make sure that when adding a new item to the ArrayList that you insert it into position 0 of the list. To do this instead of calling the normal;

```
c.add(item);
```

instead pass it the index of 0;

```
c.add(0, item);
```

This will insure that the item is inserted at the beginning of the list and will make your life a lot easier.

I hope this is enough information to get you through your problem! Good luck!

Comment: I am reversing by using Collection.reverse() and i am fetching the data from SQLite. I have another activity that inserts data in the DB. I want to display the last data inserted adjusting the previous data and taking the top position.